# SOAP service always timeout in my xamarin-android project

Tags: android, .net, web-services, xamarin, soap

I've succesfully added a wsdl reference to my Android PCL that has two methods in it, but whenever i called one of the methods it always timeout.

I want to consume the service from an android app. I've tried to add the reference to a console project and it works fine there with the same code, the Reference.cs that it generates is exactly the same in both the console and the PCL. I'm just calling the method with the given parameters, no network credentials, etc. The last parameter is just a normal xml string.

```
try
{    
    _proxy = new ServiceReference();
    _proxy.Timeout = 30000;
    var arr = _proxy.CallMethod("user", "pass", 1, $"<[CDATA[{xml}]]>");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

I'm getting the next error in the catch:

System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x000a7] in <3f9824dbe67544e1805773e0a3dbdf6b>:0

I've used other web services before and never done anything different, am im missing something here?

Comment: are you saying that one method is timing out but the other one works?

Comment: both methods timeout

Comment: are you sure the server is reachable from your device or emulator?  Are you sure your server can handle remote requests?  Have you checked the server logs to see if it is receiving requests?

Comment: yes it is from a device, yes it can, and the request is not reaching the server.

Comment: that sounds like a connectivity issue - are you SURE the server is reachable from your device?  How are you testing this?  Have you tried plugging the SOAP endpoint into the device browser to see if you get a response?

Comment: Yes it reaches the service, tried on multiple devices with wifi, 4G network and still timeout. Can't figure out why it reaches so easily from a console but not from the device.

Comment: @FernandoSaravia Is the web service on a publicly accessible network (internet/public ip) or on a private one or on your dev pc, i.e. localhost ?

Comment: yes the service is public, i cannot copy the link here due to privacy terms of the client.